# Android not catching Firestore Transaction PlatformException

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am build random 1:1 chat app in Flutter and Firebase. I am use `transaction` for add user to chat because must avoid race condition of more than 1 user be add to chat. Chat must be 1:1.

I need catch `transaction` error if `transaction` timeout.

But **error is catch only on iOS** (not Android). 
Only on iOS it catch error as show:

> PlatformException(9, Transaction failed all retries.: Every document
>   read in a transaction must also be written in that transaction., null)

**On Android in debug mode app freeze and throw error** in `message_codecs.dart` :

> throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage,
>   details: errorDetails);

Here is transaction:

```
      Future<bool> addUser() async {

    try {
      await Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        DocumentSnapshot chatRoomDocSnapshot =
            await transaction.get(chatRoomDocRef);
        bool userInChat = await chatRoomDocSnapshot[‘userInChat'];

        if (userInChat == false) {
            await transaction.update(chatRoomDocSnapshot.reference, {
              ‘userInChat': true,
            });
        }
      });

    await chatUserRef.setData({
      ‘User’: user,
    });

      userAdded = true;


    } catch (e) {
print(e);
      userAdded = false;
    }
    return userAdded;
      }
```

I am use plugin `cloud_firestore: ^0.12.5+1`

Anyone see this plugin issue?

Why only have this error on Android?

Thanks for help!

Comment: This should be a [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new).

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Thanks for reply! I am ask because maybe I am implement transaction wrong?

Comment: The implementation looks fine.